# Reading in a file, finding a substring, and writing it out to a catalog

Tags: python, string, file, catalog

This is a file, entitled "galfit.365" that I would like to read in. I need to access this file through python, find the number "10" after "Input menu file:" and find the number "39" after "w." After that, I would like to save those numbers into a catalog.

I know the general approach; read the file in, find the relevant substring, save that string, and write it out with asciitable. However, I'm sort of a Python newbie, so I'm not sure where to start. First of all, how do I "read the file in?" After that, how do I find the particular string values that I am interested in?

```
#  Input menu file: 10f160w39.feedme

#  Chi^2/nu = 0.003,  Chi^2 = 45.157,  Ndof = 16768

================================================================================
# IMAGE and GALFIT CONTROL PARAMETERS
A) NOISE10thousandthsciPHOTOF160w39.fits      # Input data image (FITS file)
B) NOISE10thousandthgalsciPHOTOF160w39.fits      # Output data image block
C) NOISE10thousandthsigmaPHOTOF160w39.fits      # Sigma image name (made from data if blank or "none") 
D) arjen_psf_f160w.fits          # Input PSF image and (optional) diffusion kernel
E) 1                   # PSF fine sampling factor relative to data 
F) maskNOISE10thousandthsciPHOTOF160w39.fits      # Bad pixel mask (FITS image or ASCII coord list)
G) none                # File with parameter constraints (ASCII file) 
H) 1    130  1    130  # Image region to fit (xmin xmax ymin ymax)
I) 200    200          # Size of the convolution box (x y)
J) 26.563              # Magnitude photometric zeropoint 
K) 0.038  0.038        # Plate scale (dx dy)   [arcsec per pixel]
O) regular             # Display type (regular, curses, both)
P) 0                   # Choose: 0=optimize, 1=model, 2=imgblock, 3=subcomps

# INITIAL FITTING PARAMETERS
#
#   For component type, the allowed functions are: 
#       sersic, expdisk, edgedisk, devauc, king, nuker, psf, 
#       gaussian, moffat, ferrer, and sky. 
#  
#   Hidden parameters will only appear when they're specified:
#       Bn (n=integer, Bending Modes).
#       C0 (diskyness/boxyness), 
#       Fn (n=integer, Azimuthal Fourier Modes).
#       R0-R10 (coordinate rotation, for creating spiral structures).
#       To, Ti, T0-T10 (truncation function).
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   par)    par value(s)    fit toggle(s)    # parameter description 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Component number: 1
 0) sersic                 #  Component type
 1) 65.6794  64.2952  1 1  #  Position x, y
 3) 23.7585     1          #  Integrated magnitude 
 4) 0.0100      1          #  R_e (effective radius)   [pix]
 5) 1.6931      1          #  Sersic index n (de Vaucouleurs n=4) 
 6) 0.0000      0          #     ----- 
 7) 0.0000      0          #     ----- 
 8) 0.0000      0          #     ----- 
 9) 0.6379      1          #  Axis ratio (b/a)  
10) -2.3601     1          #  Position angle (PA) [deg: Up=0, Left=90]
 Z) 0                      #  Skip this model in output image?  (yes=1, no=0)

# Component number: 2
 0) sky                    #  Component type
 1) 6.853e-05      1       #  Sky background at center of fitting region [ADUs]
 2) 0.000e+00      0       #  dsky/dx (sky gradient in x)     [ADUs/pix]
 3) 0.000e+00      0       #  dsky/dy (sky gradient in y)     [ADUs/pix]
 Z) 0                      #  Skip this model in output image?  (yes=1, no=0)

================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "read a file in", if it's a text file (human-readable lines of around 80 characters), you normally do it line by line. That looks like this:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        # whatever you wanted to do with each line
```

But in your case, you only want to read the very first line, and don't care about anything else, right? So:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    first_line = next(file)
    # whatever you wanted to do with first_line
```

---

Now, how do you deal with that line? A lot of people would suggest a regular expression, and `\s(\d+)f\d+w(\d+)\.` should do it, but you're not likely to understand that.

One way to do it is to find places to "split" the line to get the parts you want.

```
#  Input menu file: 10f160w39.feedme
```

If you separate that by spaces, everything you care about is in the last word, `10f160w39.feedme`. (There may also be invisible whitespace on the end—in fact, there *is* at least a newline character. I'll use `strip` to throw them away first.) So, let's start with:

```
menufile = line.strip().rsplit()[-1]
```

Now, everything before the `f` is one number, and everything between the `w` and the `.` is another right? So:

```
f = menufile.partition('f')[0]
w = menufile.rpartition('.')[0].rpartition('w')[-1]
```

And we're done.

Comment: What if I do actually want to read in later lines within the same file? For example, I need to read in line 42 ("3) 23.7585     1          #  Integrated magnitude" ), and only write out 23.7585. How would I modify my approach to account for that?

Comment: @vdogsandman: You use the `for` loop that I showed at the top, to go line by line through the file.

Comment: I'm getting this: 

      1 with open('galfit.333') as file:
      2     for line in file:
----> 3         menufile = line.strip().rsplit()[-1]
      4         f = menufile.partition('f')[0]
      5         w = menufile.rpartition('.')[0].rpartition('w')[-1]

IndexError: list index out of range

What's the issue?

Comment: @vdogsandman: Well, that code only works for the first line. The second line is empty. So, `line.strip().rsplit()` is an empty list, `[]`, so the `[-1]` on that raises an `IndexError`. You need to write some "if" statements that recognize when you're on a particular line—for example, only do the first-line code `if 'Input menu file:' in line`, only do the integrated magnitude code `if 'Integrated magnitude' in line`, etc.

Comment: @vdogsandman: Or, alternatively, if you want to count by line number, do `for line_number, line in enumerate(file)`, and then you can do `if line_number == 0:` and `if line_number == 42:` and so on. (Just remember that Python counts from 0.)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there are more elegant ways of doing this, but this will get job done and it's a nice starting point for your python travels and adventures. God speed.

```
with open("galfit.365") as file:
     lines = file.readlines() # all your lines are here

     # should print "#  Input menu file: 10f160w39.feedme"
     # since it is the first line in the file
     print lines[0]

     index_of_w = lines[0].index('w')

     # this should give you 39
     number_after_w = lines[0][index_of_w+1] + lines[0][index_of_w+2]
```

Comment: This seems like a convenient way to grab substrings; thank you so much!